# Node JS newbie: why do I get a 404? (angular-seed)

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I'm trying NodeJS for the first time.
I'm following the hello world instructions at https://github.com/angular/angular-seed and https://github.com/thedigitalself/angular-sprout (which has the same hello world instructions for a slightly modified fork of the first one).

In both cases, I'm supposed to just run a web-server.js file that is included in the repo using Node and then navigate to `http://localhost:<port>/app/index.html`

This gives me a 404 error page (which is written in the web-server.js file), as does just /app/.

But if I navigate to `http://localhost:<port>` I get a directory listing for the filesystem directory where the web-server.js script is, which is also written in web-server.js.

Any idea why web-server.js cannot find /app/ or /app/index.html?

Comment: When I forked and clone the repository to my directory and run

`node script/web-server.js` and visit this link `http://localhost:8000/app/index.html#/view1` it works for me

Comment: Hmm, that URL gives me the same error.

Comment: FYI, not sure this is relevant, but if I run `node script/web-server.js` or cd into script and run `node web-server.js` instead of just `./web-server.js`, node exits with an error that it cannot find the file `web-server.js`

Comment: I got node by just running the OSX installer, which exited successfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you run the server from your root directory.

`~/angular-seed/`

In here you do `node scripts/web-server.js`

Then you can visit

`http://localhost:<PORT>/app/index.html`

Comment: That is weird because I will get 404 when I cd to `scripts` and run `web-server.js`, but when I move back to the root and ran `script/web-server.js` then visit this `localhost:8888/` then I get list of dirs then I can go to `app` find `index.html` and no problem there.

Comment: You had the answer, but it failed for me because you wrote "script/" instead of "scripts/" which is the name of the folder. Please edit your answer.